# convert epoch time to readable time foramt

Tags: bash, shell, date

I wrote a code which convert epoch time to readable time

```
sd=`date -d '1970-01-01 UTC '$SDATE' seconds' +"%d-%m-%Y"`
```

the output is : 27-12-2002 but I want the output to be : 27/Nov/2002

how should i change my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sd=`date -d '1970-01-01 UTC '$SDATE' seconds' +"%d/%b/%Y"

I believe

Answer (score 2):

There's a shortcut for "time from unix stamp": `date -d @$STAMP`. For the output, read `man date`

Answer (score 1):

Use `%b` instead:

```
sd=`date -d '1970-01-01 UTC '$SDATE' seconds' +"%d/%b/%Y"`
```

Read `man date` for more details: